# LibGDX Android app violates API usage policies

Tags: android, libgdx

After submitting my Android app, created with LibGDX 1.9.10, I started getting loads of crashes.

After some investigations, I found that the crashes are coming from devices with Android 9 and higher (API level 28). It works fine on lower version Androids.

Investigating further, the errors I find seem to indicate that the errors are caused by LibGDX's Android launcher violating API usage policies in place since Android 9:

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

> "Starting in Android 9 (API level 28), the platform restricts which
>   non-SDK interfaces your app can use."

The errors I see look like this:

```
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425): StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/NIOAccess;->getBasePointer(Ljava/nio/Buffer;)J
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:86)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(Unknown Source:30)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at my-libgdx-app.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(Unknown Source:97)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425): StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/NIOAccess;->getBaseArray(Ljava/nio/Buffer;)Ljava/lang/Object;
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:86)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(Unknown Source:30)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at my-libgdx-app.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(Unknown Source:97)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425): StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/NIOAccess;->getBaseArrayOffset(Ljava/nio/Buffer;)I
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:86)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(Unknown Source:30)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at my-libgdx-app.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(Unknown Source:97)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425): StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->position:I
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:86)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(Unknown Source:30)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at my-libgdx-app.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(Unknown Source:97)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425): StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->limit:I
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:86)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(Unknown Source:30)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at my-libgdx-app.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(Unknown Source:97)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425): StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->_elementSizeShift:I
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:86)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(Unknown Source:30)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(Unknown Source:1)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at my-libgdx-app.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(Unknown Source:97)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
03-10 06:25:33.602: D/StrictMode(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

The log above is from Firebase Test Lab, but I am sure it represents the same error I get from actual devices in the wild.

What can I do? My crash stats are getting hammered and ratings are sure to follow :(

Comment: Your stack traces show that StrictMode is enabled. This is useful for development but typically should not be left enabled in production apps. Are you shipping your apps with StrictMode enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I am actually building the Android app with Libgdx 1.9.9 (not 1.9.10 as stated in the question). 1.9.10 should have the fix for the issue, so I am confirming it right now, will mark as answered when confirmed.